# Выделение активной ссылки бэкграундом

Tags: css

Привет всем! Пишу своего рода музыкальный каталог. В цикле (PHP) вывожу список всех песен из папки на сервере. Вот. При наведении на каждую из них, происходит выделение активной бэкграундом.

```
a:hover {
    background-color:#810002
}
```

Не могу справиться с проблемой, когда при клике на песню активная ссылка выделялась бэкграундом, чтобы пользователь знал, что слушает на данный момент, чтобы знал, на что кликнул.

Помогите решить проблему! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [http://htmlbook.ru/css/active][1]

[1]:http://htmlbook.ru/css/active

Comment: НУууууу наконец то хоть один рабочий, действительно рабочий пример нашел перепробывал сотни правда..и соjтветственно вопрос как сделать буквы белые у строки, которая выделена?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вариант на `jQuery`, который находит на странице ссылки на саму себя и выделяет

```
<style type="text/css">
   .Current
   {
       background-color: #810002;
   }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = document.location.toString();
        $("a").filter(function () {
            return url.indexOf(this.href) != -1;
        }).addClass("Current");
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Фигня полная твой вариант

Answer (score 2):

говнокод: (+php)

```
<style>  .link {background-color:#810002} </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("li a").removeClass("link");  
$("#link_<?echo (int)$_GET['id']?>").addClass("link"); 
});  
</script>

<ul>
     <li><a href="?id=1" id="link_1">link</a></li>  
     <li><a href="?id=2" id="link_2">link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="?id=3" id="link_3">link 2</a></li> 
</ul>
```

чем тебе вариант **[Tolyandre](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2701/tolyandre)** не угодил? Вполне.

Comment: Не работает пример у меня... jquery.js... откуда взять?

Comment: Пример рабочий. фреймворк jQuery можно взять на http://jquery.com/

Comment: Не пашет. Когда href=#, этот пример работает, а у меня ссылки вида: 
index.php?artist=%C3%F0.%20%CB%E0%EC%E0%ED%F5%EE%E9

Comment: переписал

Comment: Я тебе предлагаю поплотнее изучить фреймворк.